# exception handling for undefined index error?

Tags: php, error-handling

The script below is called when saving my app's options page. All options are stored in an array in $options.

I'm getting a debug error "undefined index, id" on the line with the comment below. Any ideas how I can fix the script?

```
        foreach ($options as $value) 
        {
            if( isset( $value['id'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST[$value['id']] ) ) 
            {
                update_option( $value['id'], stripslashes($_REQUEST[$value['id']])  ); 
            }
            else
            {
                update_option( $value['id'], ""); //Error Here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if{}` segment precludes the code in your `else{}` segment from working.

In other words:

In your if block, you ask: "Does $value['id'] exist?"

If it does not, your code executes your else block, which then attempts to reference the non-existent variable.

You'll need to set the array key before you can update it.

Your update_option function should simply check to see if the variable exists, and set it instead of updating it, if it does not.

Comment: using this as a basis, the OP should think about updating  `update_option()` to check if the array key exists before updating that key, and if the key != exist, create it first

Comment: Hmm, that was my intention.  I guess it wasn't clear.  Thanks for clarifying.